# Heroku is not including headers with assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Currently I'm using unicorn server with `rails_12factor` gem in order to serve assets from rails server. The main application url is returning correct response headers, but the assets urls return responses without some headers (e.g `Cache-Control`) and I need them for proper app functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with adding

```
config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=1000'
```

to `production.rb`.